# Can't save quiz answers

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build quiz system and i'm stuck on this.

```
  public function store(Quizze $quizzes)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'title.title' => 'required',
            'questions.*.question' => 'required',
            'answers.*.answer' => 'required',
        ], [
            'title.title.required' => 'გთხოვთ, შეიყვანოთ ქვიზის სახელი.',
            'questions.*.question.required' => 'გთხოვთ, შეიყვანოთ შეკითხვა.',
            'answers.*.answer.required' => 'გთხოვთ, შეიყვანოთ პასუხი.'
        ]);
        $storeQuiz = $quizzes->create($data['title']);
        $storeQuiz->questions()->createMany($data['questions']);
        $storeQuiz->questions()->answers()->createMany($data['answers']);
        return redirect('admin/quizzes');
    }
```

It's saving quiz title and quiz question but it's errors on questions it don't like

```
 $storeQuiz->questions()->answers()->createMany($data['answers']);
```

It's errors Call to undefined method `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::answers()`

Quiz Model relation:

```
public function questions() { 
    return $this->hasMany(QuizQuestion::class, 'quizze_id', 'id'); 
}
```

Question Model relation :

```
public function answers() { 
    return $this->hasMany(QuizAnswer::class, 'question_id', 'id'); 
}
```

Comment: Post your model

Comment: quiz:   public function questions() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(QuizQuestion::class, 'quizze_id', 'id');
    }    question: public function answers() {
        return $this->hasMany(QuizAnswer::class, 'question_id', 'id');
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
$storeQuiz->questions()->answers()->createMany($data['answers']);
```

`answers()` does not recognize the `question`. You can try this :

```
$storeQuiz = $quizzes->create($data['title']);

foreach($data['questions'] as $q){
    $question = $storeQuiz->questions()->create($q);
    $question->answers()->createMany($data['answers']);
}
```