# Quiz questions create

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i'm building quiz system and i'm stuck on this problem.
Trying to save quiz but it's errors

```
 <form action="/admin/quiz/store" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title">ქვიზის დასახელება</label>
                            <input name="title[title]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('title.title') }}" id="title" placeholder="">
                            @error('title.title')
                            <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="question2">ქვიზის შეკითხვა</label>
                            <input name="questions[1][question]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('questions.0.question') }}" id="question1" placeholder="">
                            @error('questions.0.question')
                            <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="question1answer1">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                                        <input name="questions[1][answers][]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('answers.0.answer') }}" id="question1answer1" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                                        @error('answers.0.answer')
                                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="question1answer2">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                                        <input name="questions[1][answers][]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('answers.1.answer') }}" id="question1answer2" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                                        @error('answers.1.answer')
                                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="question1answer3">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                                        <input name="questions[1][answers][]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('answers.2.answer') }}" id="question1answer3" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                                        @error('answers.2.answer')
                                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="question1answer4">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                                        <input name="questions[1][answers][]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('answers.3.answer') }}" id="question1answer4" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                                        @error('answers.3.answer')
                                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        meore shekitxva
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="question2">ქვიზის შეკითხვა</label>
                            <input name="questions[2][question]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('questions.0.question') }}" id="question2" placeholder="">
                            @error('questions.0.question')
                            <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="question2answer1">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                                        <input name="questions[2][answers][]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('answers.0.answer') }}" id="question2answer1" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                                        @error('answers.0.answer')
                                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="question2answer2">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                                        <input name="questions[2][answers][]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('answers.1.answer') }}" id="question2answer2" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                                        @error('answers.1.answer')
                                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="question2answer3">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                                        <input name="questions[2][answers][]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('answers.2.answer') }}" id="question2answer3" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                                        @error('answers.2.answer')
                                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="question2answer4">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                                        <input name="questions[2][answers][]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('answers.3.answer') }}" id="question2answer4" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                                        @error('answers.3.answer')
                                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ქვიზის დამატება</button>
                    </form>
```

Its gives Undefined array key "answers" so i really don't understand why it's giving me this error...

I was creating like this answers[][answer]  but it was saving quiz title and questions normal but in answers table it was saving first question answers in question_id=1 and question_id=2 and it's saves second question same.

Then someone told me to do questions[1][answers][] but now i'm getting Undefined array key "answers"

saving controller

```
   public function store(Quizze $quizzes)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'title.title' => 'required',
            'questions.*.question' => 'required',
            'answers.*.answer' => 'required',
        ], [
            'title.title.required' => 'გთხოვთ, შეიყვანოთ ქვიზის სახელი.',
            'questions.*.question.required' => 'გთხოვთ, შეიყვანოთ შეკითხვა.',
            'answers.*.answer.required' => 'გთხოვთ, შეიყვანოთ პასუხი.'
        ]);
        $storeQuiz = $quizzes->create($data['title']);
        foreach ($data['questions'] as $q) {
            $question = $storeQuiz->questions()->create($q);
            $question->answers()->createMany($data['answers']);
        }
        return redirect('admin/quizzes');
    }
```

please can someone help me with this...
sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You have an input named "questions[2][answers][]" but then you attempt to validate "answers.*.answer".  Of course the validation should be looking at "questions.*.answers.*"

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your loop :

```
foreach ($data['questions'] as $key => $q) {
    $question = $storeQuiz->questions()->create(['question' => $q['question']]);
    $question->answers()->createMany($data['questions'][$key]['answers']);
}
```

#### Update

There's no `answers` data (ref by comment), because validation. You need to change validation :

```
'title.title' => 'required',
'questions.*.question' => 'required',
'questions.*.answers.*.answer' => 'required',
```

And HTML :

```
<form action="/admin/quiz/store" method="POST">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">ქვიზის დასახელება</label>
        <input name="title[title]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('title.title') }}" id="title" placeholder="">
        @error('title.title')
        <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
        @enderror
    </div>

    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="question2">ქვიზის შეკითხვა</label>
        <input name="questions[1][question]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('questions.0.question') }}" id="question1" placeholder="">
        @error('questions.0.question')
        <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="question1answer1">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                    <input name="questions[1][answers][][answer]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('questions.1.answers.0.answer') }}" id="question1answer1" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                    @error('questions.1.answers.0.answer')
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="question1answer2">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                    <input name="questions[1][answers][][answer]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('questions.1.answers.1.answer') }}" id="question1answer2" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                    @error('questions.1.answers.1.answer')
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="question1answer3">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                    <input name="questions[1][answers][][answer]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('questions.1.answers.2.answer') }}" id="question1answer3" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                    @error('questions.1.answers.2.answer')
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="question1answer4">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                    <input name="questions[1][answers][][answer]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('questions.1.answers.3.answer') }}" id="question1answer4" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                    @error('questions.1.answers.3.answer')
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
           
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    meore shekitxva
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="question2">ქვიზის შეკითხვა</label>
        <input name="questions[2][question]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('questions.0.question') }}" id="question2" placeholder="">
        @error('questions.0.question')
        <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
        @enderror
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="question2answer1">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                    <input name="questions[2][answers][][answer]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('questions.2.answers.0.answer') }}" id="question2answer1" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                    @error('questions.2.answers.0.answer')
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="question2answer2">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                    <input name="questions[2][answers][][answer]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('questions.2.answers.1.answer') }}" id="question2answer2" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                    @error('questions.2.answers.1.answer')
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="question2answer3">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                    <input name="questions[2][answers][][answer]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('questions.2.answers.2.answer') }}" id="question2answer3" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                    @error('questions.2.answers.2.answer')
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="question2answer4">ქვიზის პასუხი</label>
                    <input name="questions[2][answers][][answer]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('questions.2.answers.3.answer') }}" id="question2answer4" aria-describedby="choicesHelp" placeholder="">
                    @error('questions.2.answers.3.answer')
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
           
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ქვიზის დამატება</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is that you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69809861/984422

Comment: Thanks for answer but i'm getting same error. what i must change in blade? after i change it in controller?

Comment: Can you run `dd($data)` before `$storeQuiz` declaration? What the output?

Comment: Yes i can't add question in that account and i must make this working today so i created new account... (

Comment: array:2 [▼
  "title" => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "asdasd"
  ]
  "questions" => array:2 [▼
    1 => array:1 [▼
      "question" => "asdas"
    ]
    2 => array:1 [▼
      "question" => "asdsad"
    ]
  ]
]

Comment: There's no `answers`. Check my update

Comment: Thanks for answer :) but now i'm getting Array to string conversion error

Comment: Yes, updated. Please check

Comment: Thansk i coped blade and changed in 'questions.*.answers.*.answer' => 'required', but i'm still getting  Array to string conversion

Comment: Did you update error message too? `'questions.*.answers.*.answer' => 'გთხოვთ, შეიყვანოთ პასუხი.'`

Comment: Yes i updated it but same error (

Comment: Can you post an error message? Or screenshot?

Comment: i'm not getting validator error when i push submit button i'm getting  " ErrorException
Array to string conversion "

Comment: Oh i see.. Try to change this `$question = $storeQuiz->questions()->create(['question' => $q['question']]);`

Comment: Big big big thanks for your help <3 : )

Comment: np. glad to help